# Is it possible to add HTML within an If statement in Javascript and Close the Script Tag?

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner with Javascript and I'm trying to create one IF call. The goal is to say "If the screen size is > X then input my adsense code.

If this were PHP when I could create a PHP tag and then close it and insert the html then close the IF tag in PHP. Is this possible in Javascript? Here's what my code looks like in an ideal world.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if ( $(window).width() > 739)  {
    document.write('<div id="banner-left">');
</script>

[My Adsense Code]

<script type="text/javascript">
} //close if
</script>
```

Tried this and definitely doesn't work. Is there another way to do this without rewriting the Adsense code in full javascript?

Thanks for taking the time to look through my question.

Comment: Better to achieve this by css3. You may read more about media rule. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: Have you tried CSS ? you can write a CSS style for each different size category you want

Comment: You can just unconditionally add the HTML code & mark that tag's style as `display:none`. Then using javascript, you can change its style.

Comment: Not using CSS because W3 Total Cache is caching the req.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a string and write it like this -

```
<script>
if($(window).width() > 739 ){
    var str;
    str = "";
    str += "<div id='banner-left'>";
    str += "<div class='adsense-outer'>";
    //here add your Adsense code like this i.e. concate the string
    str += "</div>";
    str += "</div>";
    document.write(str);
}
</script>
```

Comment: This actually worked with a little modification. Thanks. Can't believe I didn't try this.

Comment: Sometimes it happen. Not a fact, carry on.

Answer (score 1):

You can write code that would append an element onto the document if a certain condition is met. Choose what element you want to append the banner on and reference it in your code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    if($(window).width() > 739)  {

        // This will be the element you want to attach your banner to
        var parent = document.getElementById('id-of-element-to-append');

        // Here you can create your banner element in javascript
        var banner = document.createElement('div');
        banner.id = 'banner-left';
        banner.innerHTML = 'Contents of your banner';
        parent.appendChild(banner);
    }

</script>
```

Javascript works very differently than PHP. In PHP, you're able to manipulate what will appear on the page *before* it's rendered in the browser, but in javascript, you can only manipulate what already exists.

Comment: Thanks. The logic seems to make sense, but I'm wondering where to insert the adsense code. Thanks for taking the time to respond, Nick. The "innerHTML" part won't work as the content is Adsense code which includes both HTML and JS.

Comment: @user1701252 Is the adsense code some block of javascript code?

Comment: Yes. Has a mix of script src="URL" then some HTML then a block of JS then another block of HTML then another script SRC.

Comment: @user1701252 try to just add that code in the if statement after the element is created and mounted

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if ( $(window).width() > 739) {    
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  document.body.appendChild(div);
  div.id = 'banner-left';
  div.innerHTML = '<span class="msg">Hi</span>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using responsive adsense ad units. https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/3213689?hl=en They would not exactly hide, but would adapt according to the device screen size if combined with responsive CSS framework such as twitter bootstrap. So the ad that looks like big square on a sidebar on a desktop would render as a tiny banner on mobile without any additional coding on your side.